# Elixir/Phoenix - how to add variables value to fragment

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have query to database:

```
Repo.all(from d in ScannerData,
          where: d.unixdate >= ^dates.start_date,
          order_by: [desc: fragment("?", ^order_by)],
          group_by: d.host,
          limit: 10,
          select: %{
            recipient: d.host,
            email_count: fragment("COUNT(crc)"),
            duration_sum: fragment("SUM(duration)"),
            ham_duration_sum: fragment("SUM(CASE WHEN scanner = 'Clear' THEN duration ELSE 0 END)"),
            spam_duration_sum: fragment("SUM(CASE WHEN scanner != 'Clear' THEN duration ELSE 0 END)")
          }
      )
```

The request contains a string that is responsible for sorting:

> order_by: [desc: fragment("?", ^order_by)]

Depending on the situation, sorting can be done in different ways, so I use a variable **order_by**.

```
order_by = case params["sort"] do
  "email_count" -> "COUNT(crc)"
  "size_sum" -> "SUM(size)"
  "duration_sum" -> "SUM(duration)"
  "ham_duration_sum" -> "SUM(CASE WHEN scanner = 'Clear' THEN duration ELSE 0 END)"
  "spam_duration_sum" -> "SUM(CASE WHEN scanner != 'Clear' THEN duration ELSE 0 END)"
  _ -> "COUNT(crc)"
end
```

But sorting not work. If I use:

```
order_by: [desc: fragment(^order_by)]
```

I have an error:

> to prevent SQL injection attacks, fragment(...) does not allow strings
>   to be interpolated as the first argument via the `^` operator, got:
>   `"SUM(size)"`

I will be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to order by dynamic values, one needs to explicitly declare [`Ecto.Query.dynamic/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html?#dynamic/2-order_by). That said, the following would work:

```rb
order_by: ^[desc: dynamic([d], fragment("?", order_by))]
```

Comment: unfortunately did not work :( I tried your way, also tried to substitute the value directly: order_by: ^[desc: dynamic([d], fragment("?", "SUM(size)"))]
But when I do this: ^[desc: dynamic([d], fragment("SUM(size)"))] sorting works

Comment: I do not follow. Does it work or does not it work? The approach above is surely correct, without seeing the real `order_by` I cannot tell anything else.

Comment: I need the value to be substituted from a variable. If I do this: ^[desc: dynamic([d], fragment("?", ^order_by))] or this  ^[desc: dynamic([d], fragment("?", "SUM(size)"))]  - sorting not working.

Comment: In the former, the `order_by` argument should not be pinned. In the latter, it should be `fragment("SUM(?)", size)`.